# Accessing value through material ui ListItemText component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have material ui components like:

```
                  <ListItemText onClick={(ev) => onAreaSelect(ev)} primary={area} />
                </ListItem>
```

And then:

```
  const onAreaSelect = (event) => {
      console.log("area seledcted??", event.target, event.target.value)
  }
```

`event.target` returns:

```
<span class="MuiTypography-root MuiListItemText-primary MuiTypography-body1 MuiTypography-displayBlock"> Area </span>
```

but `event.target.value`  returns:

```
undefined
```

how can I access the value?

Answer (score 1):

1. `useRef()`which will hold the value of the element you put `ref` field in like so:

   ```
       const areaRef = useREf(null)
       .
       .
       <ListItemText ref = {areaRef} onClick={(ev) => onAreaSelect(ev)} 
      primary={area} />
   ```
2. `onChange()` has two params : event and value so you can do something like this :

   ```
     onChange((event,value)=>onAreaSelect(event,value))
   ```

Comment: value comes up as undefined as well

Comment: have you tried to put the `onClick()` in the `ListItem` and not the `ListItemText`?

Comment: Yes, it also gets undefined for both, `value` and `event.target.value`

Comment: I don't understand in your answer why is the useRef necessary. I have 3 lists with ListItemText, the 3 of them having the same onClick event

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and came up with a work through around this..
you can pass the "area" with event in your function onAreaSelect

For example like this:

```
<ListItemText onClick={(ev) => onAreaSelect(ev,{area})} primary={area} />
        </ListItem> 

const onAreaSelect = (event, area) => {
console.log("area selected??", event.target, area)
}
```